# SystemClock_config() timeout while using the keil Simulator

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, keil, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

In this example I will use SPI2 run in mode Master(NSS pin control by software) to send data.
SPI3 run in mode Slave (NSS pin control by harware) receive data using DMA.

PC2 (SPI2 MISO) connect to PC11(SPI3 MISO).
PC3 (SPI2 MOSI) connect to PC12(SPI3 MOSI).
PB10 (SPI2 SCK) connect to PC10 (SPI3 SCK).
PC6 (SPI2 NSS pin control by sofware) connect to PA4(SPI3 NSS pin control by hardware).

**main.c**

```
    #include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"



#define spi_enable      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_RESET)
#define spi_disable   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_SET)

SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi2;
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi3;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_spi3_rx;





void SystemClock_Config(void);
void Error_Handler(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI2_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI3_Init(void);



uint8_t send_data=32,receive_data=0;



int main(void)
{



  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_SPI2_Init();
  MX_SPI3_Init();

  HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA(&hspi3,&receive_data,1);




  while (1)
  {

        spi_enable;
        HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT(&hspi2,&send_data,1);
        HAL_Delay(1000);
        send_data++;
  }



}

void HAL_SPI_TxCpltCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi)
{
    if(hspi->Instance==hspi2.Instance)
    {
        spi_disable;
    }
}

/** System Clock Configuration
*/
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}

/* SPI2 init function */
static void MX_SPI2_Init(void)
{

  hspi2.Instance = SPI2;
  hspi2.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi2.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi2.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi2.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi2.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi2.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi2.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
  hspi2.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi2.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi2.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi2.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}

/* SPI3 init function */
static void MX_SPI3_Init(void)
{

  hspi3.Instance = SPI3;
  hspi3.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
  hspi3.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi3.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi3.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi3.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi3.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_HARD_INPUT;
  hspi3.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi3.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi3.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi3.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}

/** 
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void) 
{
  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Stream0_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Stream0_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Stream0_IRQn);

}

/** Configure pins as 
        * Analog 
        * Input 
        * Output
        * EVENT_OUT
        * EXTI
*/
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PC6 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  while(1) 
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler */ 
}

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
   * @brief Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
   * where the assert_param error has occurred.
   * @param file: pointer to the source file name
   * @param line: assert_param error line source number
   * @retval None
   */
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
    ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */

}

#endif

/**
  * @}
  */ 

/**
  * @}
*/ 

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

During debugging, I found that SystemClock_config() function continuously  running given below code.

```
/* Wait till HSE is ready */  
    while(__HAL_RCC_GET_FLAG(RCC_FLAG_HSERDY) == RESET)
    {
      if((HAL_GetTick() - tickstart ) > HSE_TIMEOUT_VALUE)
      {
        return HAL_TIMEOUT;
      }
```

why is it not going to further function?

Comment: I afraid the simulator for such complex micros are completely useless. They newer work as expected. But in this case probably you did not configure the simulator to use HSE oscillator. My advice - buy cheap STM32F4 nucleo board (it costs less than the a pack of cigarettes) and stop using simulators.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving valuable response..!!!!! @PeterJ

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RTOS this could help:
http://www.keil.com/support/docs/3931.htm

Therefore the CMSIS RTOS already configures the priorities for some interrupts. Try to uncomment following code from SystemClock_Config() additionally to the description:

```
 //HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

 //HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

 /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
 //HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: May be this step after below condition will be satisfied.    if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }    this function is continuously running

Comment: Perheps your systick isn't working. Try to manually implement HAL_GetTick(void) in your main.c        uint32_t HAL_GetTick(void) {
  static uint32_t ticks = 0U; 
  uint32_t i; 
  
  if (osKernelGetState () == osKernelRunning) { 
    return ((uint32_t)osKernelGetTickCount ()); 
  }
  /* If Kernel is not running wait approximately 1 ms then increment and return auxiliary tick counter value */ 
 for (i = (SystemCoreClock >> 14U); i > 0U; i--) { __NOP(); __NOP(); __NOP(); __NOP(); __NOP(); __NOP(); __NOP(); __NOP(); __NOP(); __NOP(); __NOP(); __NOP(); } 

 return ++ticks; 
}